# Do I need to use OpenGL to draw at the pixel by pixel level (Python). Is there a way I can do such a thing without using a code library?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, 3d, pygame

I have written some code in Python which allows 3D objects to be defined in 3D object space and mapped onto a 2D screen. Currently the finished 2D polygons are drawn on the screen using the PyGame library, which works effectively, but I would like to go the full way and write code myself to complete the drawing operations PyGame does for me. This means I would like to manually control the drawing of each pixel on the screen, with the use of GPU support to accelerate the entire rendering process. From some reading it seems OpenGL is suitable for this sort of thing, but I'm not sure what the complete purpose of OpenGL is and whether I could achieve what I am trying to do in a better way. Do I really need to use OpenGL? Or is there another way for me to directly access my GPU to draw at the pixel by pixel level?

Comment: "*This means I would like to manually control the drawing of each pixel on the screen, with the use of GPU support to accelerate the entire rendering process.*" Those are diametrically opposed goals. By definition, if you are manually doing the drawing... the GPU is *not* doing the drawing. Because you are. So what exactly do you want?

Comment: Also, Pygame is already using OpenGL, so what's the point in using it yourself?

Comment: My reasoning for getting rid of Pygame is the fact that it does not utilise GPU power. By manually controlling the pixels, I mean writing the code myself that the GPU would use to draw the pixels onto the screen with the right colour. The main reason I would like to use the GPU is to make use of it's parallel nature to speed up the rendering of the objects.

Comment: "*By manually controlling the pixels, I mean writing the code myself that the GPU would use to draw the pixels onto the screen with the right colour.*" Either you are "manually controlling the pixels", or the GPU is controlling the pixels, and you're telling the GPU what to render. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thank you for your input. I think I will probably go down the route of telling the GPU what to render.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like OpenGL's programmable shaders are what you're looking for (in particular fragment shaders). They run massively parallel on a pixel-by-pixel basis, in the sense that basically you write a function that takes a single pixel location and computes its color. Note that this means that the individual pixels can't exchange information, though there are certain ways around that.

(Technically when I said "pixel" I meant "fragment", which is sort of a generalized version of a pixel.)

Comment: If you tell me more about what you're trying to render, I can add more detail.

Comment: This sounds very useful, I will definitely be looking into this. I am working on a program which allows you to create 3D models, similar to what SolidWorks would allow you to do when designing, just not as advanced. My main goal would be to allow many different generic objects to be created such as cubes, prism's, sphere's, which can then be sized and transformed to create the entire peice. I have already created my own classes to generate and transform these objects, and work out what would need to be drawn onto the 2D screen. I would just like a way to use the GPU to speed up the rendering.

Comment: Oh no, that won't work out, that's not a good use of fragment shaders. Unless you're an absolute wizard using cutting-edge algorithms and super advanced GPU features (which aren't shaders), you should definitely stick to rendering polygons for best performance.

Comment: Instead, a good approach to improve performance would be to let the GPU work out what parts of which objects should be drawn onto the 2D screen, instead of doing the math yourself on the CPU. Use constant vertex arrays for all your geometric primitives, then use matrix transformations to place them in view space properly.